# In Cygwin, how do I change a directory's user id UID and group id GID to zero?

Tags: cygwin

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-12/msg00005.html
"All directories from root to the chroot directory must be owned by UID 0 and GID 0. For example, if you want to jail users in /jail then / and /jail must belong to (0, 0)."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a 0:0 user:group entry like this in `/etc/password`:

```
root:*:0:0:,S-1-5-32-544::
```

And a group 0 entry in `/etc/group`:

```
root:S-1-5-32-544:0:
```

This SID is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980032.aspx 
BUILTIN_ADMINISTRATORS: S-1-5-32-544

Now you can use this chown command:

```
chown root:root /
chown root:root /jail
```